# Delete the parent folder keeping all content

Tags: linux, filesystems, rm

I want to delete my parent directory but keep all of its content. Currently my directory structure

```
$ /usermanagement/usermanagement/file1
```

After deleting my parent directory I want to see like  bellow structure

```
$ /usermanagement/file1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I didn't understand your question properly. But the answer of what I have gathered from your question is,

> Assuming you are in current directory, which name is `nested` and parent directory name is `test`.

`$ cp -Rp . ../;cd ../;rm -rf nested`

### Explanation

---

1. `cp -Rp . ../` - This will copy all files including directory, nested directory and hidden files. Where,

   - `-R` flag is used for "copy directories recursively"
   - `-p` is to "preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr, all",
   - `.` is for indicating of current directory as source
   - `..` indicating as parent directory as destination.
2. `cd ../` - This will move you from current to parent directory
3. `rm -rf nested` - This will remove all the files including directories, nested directories and hidden files.

Sources: Man page

Comment: For directories with lots of data, this will take much longer than moving/renaming.  If the data is very large, the `cp` may fail.  The final `rm` is going to run whether there were problems or not.

Comment: Ok, that's scary. I have copied 1 tb of data with cp. Yes that may be slower but I didn't experience a scenario where cp failed.

Answer (score 7):

(assuming the directory you want to remove is the current working directory)

With `zsh`:

```
cd -P . &&
  mv -- *(D) .. &&
  cd -P .. &&
  rmdir ~-
```

With `bash`:

```
cd -P . &&
  (shopt -s dotglob && mv -- * ..) &&
  cd -P .. &&
  rmdir "$OLDPWD"
```

`cd -P .` makes sure the current working directory as stored in `$PWD` is symlink-free. We want to move all files and directories into the parent, including the hidden ones (hence the `(D)` globbing flag and `dotglob` options).

If that worked we change the current directory one level up and remove our previous directory.

(you may want to add a `-i` option to `mv` to get a chance to cancel moves that would overwrite files)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution than the ones above is:

```
mv /usermanagement/usermanagement /usermanagement.tmp
rmdir /usermanagement
mv /usermanagement.tmp /usermanagement
```

I.e. move the lower `usermanagement` directory to the root directory with a temporary name, remove the (now empty) upper `usermanagement` directory, and finally rename the `/usermanagement.tmp` directory to `/usermanagement`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most simple solution:

```
$ mv /usermanagement/usermanagement/* /usermanagement/ && rmdir /usermanagement/usermanagement
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by simplest. If you have a million files in the directory, you would have a million calls to `rename`, except that you would probably get an `argument too long` error. You would also have to watch out for a file or directory named `usermanagement` in the subdirectory.